# My try/catch keeps catching the correct information and re asking, but only once. In Java

Tags: java

// this is my code. It will only spit out that last bit of information (wallet and name) the second time i put in the players number

```
String option;
        Boolean validChoice = false;
        while(!validChoice){
              option = gameScanner.nextLine();

              try {
                     selectedPlayer = Integer.parseInt(option);
                     if (selectedPlayer<0|| selectedPlayer>playerNames.length) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid choice!: Please pick another number"); 
                     }else {
                            validChoice = true;
                     }

              } catch(Exception ex){
                     selectedPlayer = -1;
                     System.out.println("Invalid choice!: Please pick another number");
              }

        }



                System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("PLAYER INFO");
        System.out.println("Name: " + playerNames[selectedPlayer]);
        System.out.println("Wallet: " + playerWallets[selectedPlayer]);
```

Comment: The numbers of the players rance from 0-4

Comment: You'll probably understand what's happening if you step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: Why is selectedPlayer not a local variable?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** your if condition is not correct.as you are taking array index value as input(index always starts from 0) you should always check for both `greater than or equal` of `length` instead of only `greater than` of `length` of the array.

**Reason for failure:**  assume your `playerNames` array contains 5 items means length = 5. so validChoid would be between 0 to 4 as array index starts from 0.

in the code as you have given wrong condition `selectedPlayer>playerNames.length` if the user enters 5(invalid) which will not satisfy above condition and then goes to else block setting the `validChoice` to `true` though it is invalid choice. as soon as `validChoice` becomes `true` it comes out from the while loop.

**Solution:** change the if condition from this :

```
if (selectedPlayer<0|| selectedPlayer>playerNames.length)
```

to this:

```
if (selectedPlayer<0 || selectedPlayer >= playerNames.length)
```

**Complete Solution:**

```
        String option;
        Boolean validChoice = false;
        while(!validChoice){
              option = gameScanner.nextLine();

              try {
                     selectedPlayer = Integer.parseInt(option);
                     if (selectedPlayer<0 || selectedPlayer>=playerNames.length) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid choice!: Please pick another number"); 
                     }else {
                            validChoice = true;
                     }

              } catch(Exception ex){
                     selectedPlayer = -1;
                     System.out.println("Invalid choice!: Please pick another number");
              }

        }



                System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("PLAYER INFO");
        System.out.println("Name: " + playerNames[selectedPlayer]);
        System.out.println("Wallet: " + playerWallets[selectedPlayer]);
```

Comment: In which situation would `validChoice` be `true` in the catch block?

Comment: In which situation would `validChoice` be `true` in the `try` block either? It's initialized to `false` right before the loop.

Comment: @kviiri: check my edited answer if the option is not between 0-4(whatever length) then `validChoice`  becomes `false` so loop continues, if it is between 0-length then becomes `true`. in catch block it should always become `false'.

Comment: Uh, you're making `validChoice = true` if `selectedPlayer` is not in range [0..playerNames.length]. That's pretty much the opposite of what the program is supposed to do...

Comment: @kviiri: yes yes, i have edited my answer...now please check and let me know.

Comment: Much better! `selectedPlayer>playerNames.length` is still incorrect though (it should be `>=` to prevent overflows). However I still don't see why `validChoice` needs to be set to `false` again inside the loop as it is already set once before the loop and the only time when it can change also means exiting the loop. I can't see any way it could become `true` without an actually correct input from the user.

Comment: @kviiri : you are right `selectedPlayer` should be always < `playerNames.length` i have added. Thanks :)

Comment: @kviiri: yes i agree with you, in try block `validChoice` need not to be set to `false` but it needs to be set to `false` in catch block to enter into the `while` loop as if user enters invaid character for `choice` .

Comment: But in that case it would already be `false`, wouldn't it? It won't be set to `true` if the input value is faulty.

Comment: @kviiri: yes :) then the OP problem is exactly here => in the code as he has given wrong condition `selectedPlayer>playerNames.length` here if user enters 4 which will not satisfy above condition and then goes to else block setting the `validChoice` to `true`. it terminates the while loop, so the changing the condition to `selectedPlayer>=playerNames.length` should solve the problem.

Comment: @kviiri: see my edited answer and please let me know if anything is missing.